# Parametrization along the coordinate axis.

Tags: linear-algebra, parametrization

I'm looking for a parametrization along the coordinate axis that goes from $(x,y)=(x_0,0)$ to $(0,0)$ and then from $(0,0)$ to $(0,x_0)$, and I know that my x-component will have to be $x_0-t$ but I somehow can't figure out the y-component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to parametrisize this, but you could use, for example
$$
\begin{cases}
x = x_0\frac{|t|-t}{2}\\
y = x_0\frac{|t|+t}{2}
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{with} \qquad -1 \leq t \leq 1
$$